# Lightweight equivalent of \cref and \Cref

Tags: cross-referencing, html, cleveref, hevea

I'm trying to convert my LaTeX document to HTML using HeVeA and I'm facing a problem with `cleveref` package -- my LaTeX file uses `\cref` and `\Cref` heavily, but hevea doesn't support this package by default.

First thing I tried was importing whole `cleveref.sty` -- that somehow didn't work, I was also looking at `cleveref` source, but that is a little too complex for me :-)

So the question is -- how do you think is a best way to do references in document that is supposed to be converted with HeVeA?

example of this is really trivial:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\label{x}
\Cref{x}, \cref{x}.
\end{document}
```

run pdflatex on this twice and you get a nice pdf with 'Section 1, section 1'. HeVeA fails with `Command not found: \Cref`

Comment: Have you looked at poor man's cleveref (section 10 of the cleveref manual)?

Comment: Have you considered using `TeX4ht` instead of `HeVeA`? It would be helpful if you posted an MWE (minimum working example) that demonstrates the problems that you're encountering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [`cleveref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/cleveref) actually has a way that you can fix this.

Let's say that your file looks something like this

**`myfile.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}\label{sec:test}
We see in \cref{sec:test} that ...
\end{document}
```

When you want to get the benefits of `cleveref` but without using `cref` and friends, then you load

```
\usepackage[poorman]{cleveref}
```

and then recompile. This produces the file `myfile.sed` (which has a lot of lines). Now run

```
sed -f myfile.sed myfile.tex> mynewfile.tex
```

which gives

**`myfilenew.tex`**

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}

\section{My section}\label{sec:test}
We see in section\nobreakspace \ref {sec:test} that ...
\end{document}
```

You now have a file that has all the benefits of `cleveref` but without any of the manual labour- sweet!

Comment: Poor man's cleveref would work, but I would need to modify the source and it would complicate the build process. My Makefile is pretty hardcore even without it :-)

Comment: And I'd also have to run sed on *all* of my *.tex files!

Comment: If you're building from a Makefile anyway, why is adding a couple more processing steps such a big issue? (latex+cleveref->sed->latex->whatever instead of latex+cleveref->whatever.) Automating this kind of thing is exactly what make excels at!?