# Making uses of cleveref packages standalone

Tags: cross-referencing, programming, cleveref

I have used `cleveref` package for referring to equations, figures, etc in an article. However, I wish to compile my tex file on another system which only has a basic version of tex. I wish to make my tex file sort of *stand-alone* .

Is there any way I can use a code which will look at my use of formatting references and replace all `\cref` commands with `\ref` commands but in the appropriate format.

Ex. when I use:

```
\crefformat{figure}{Fig.~(#2{}#1{}#3)}
\crefformat{section}{Sec.~(#2{}#1{}#3)}
\crefformat{equation}{Eq.~(#2{}#1{}#3)}
```

It should replace the instances of:

```
\cref{fig:label-for-fig}
\cref{eq:label-for-eq}
\cref{sec:label-for-sec}
```

by:

```
Fig. \ref{fig:label-for-fig}
Eq. \ref{eq:label-for-eq}
Sec. \ref{sec:label-for-sec}
```

(respectively).

Can anyone suggests a code that already exists ? Any language is ok if I can manage to run it on my system.

Comment: An option could be to use [boundle-doc](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/bundledoc/) which is a script that collects from your system all the files needed for the compilation of your document and packages them so that you can compile it in another system even if it lacks some packages.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just copy the `.sty` file of `cleveref` to your document's directory.

Comment: @Bordaigorl Sorry if I wasn't clear. I intend to make the tex file compile as a single file, without needing any style files, etc. I want the directory to have just the tex file and the images it needs.

Comment: Well, the `arlatex` script in bounde-doc may still help...

Comment: I'd be tempted to call this a duplicate of [Lightweight equivalent of \cref and \Cref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97416); please confirm if this resolves the issue, and we can close it :) Otherwise, please say how your question is different

Comment: Since you have a response below that seems to answer your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

Trying to reproduce the behavior of `cleveref` without having it is just a waste of time and hopeless: it's a large package and does things in a, well, clever way.

I don't think you'll use the system with the basic TeX distribution for producing the final version of your document, so delving with those prefixes has dubious usefulness.

Just add to your preamble

```
\IfFileExists{cleveref.sty}
  {\usepackage{cleveref}}
  {\let\cref\ref\newcommand\crefformat[2]{}}
```

and that would be all.

Comment: +1 but I think `poormans` version is the way to go, as in [Lightweight equivalent of \cref and \Cref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97416)

Comment: @cmhughes - the poorman's method is a one-way street. I believe the OP is looking for a (sadly nonexistent) method by which his/her `\cref` commands produce the same output on machines with and without the `cleveref` package being present.